# masonry with infinitescroll wont work in ie8

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, wordpress-theming

when view the page on ie8 it gives the following error: any solutions??

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; BRI/2; BOIE8;ENUS)
Timestamp: Thu, 23 Aug 2012 18:18:49 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 357
Char: 4
Code: 0

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('.two-thirds-cloumn');
$('.widgets-cout').masonry({ singleMode: true });

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.brick',
    columnWidth: 485
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '.nav-previous',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '.nav-previous a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.brick',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    },
  behavior: 'twitter',
  },

  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);


});
```